# Change the Text color of Disabled Controls in Custom Web part

Tags: design

I have a custom Form in Web part, When I am disable the panels, all the controls displayed in gray color, I know it is System Color, Is there any way we can change the color of Disabled controls for IE.. ?

Thanks

Comment: could you be more clear?

Comment: I have two panels in web form.. and I have disable the one panel. all the control color become gray. and it is not clearly visible, i want some different color, Black when the contols are disable...

Comment: Ok mate, you need to modify your CSS on-the-fly or by a CSS file. If you update the question and show to me the used CSS classes I can reply to you

Comment: I have not used any css. I am just disable the panel.. and by default controls in panel appears in gray color.. and I dont want to display in gray color..

Comment: my suggestion is use CSS

Comment: can you suggest the CSS...?